# get CSS Selector based on a siblings child

Tags: css, css-selectors, siblings

I have a dom tree like this:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="sub_a"></div>
</div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Is there a selector that can change the elements with class `b`, if class `a sub_a` exists?

Comment: You'll have to use JS.

Comment: Not possible since CSS cannot look "up". Your best bet is JS, OR editing your DOM (perhaps set `<div class="a with-sub">`) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot achieve your desired result exactly without JavaScript.
You can however check if `div.a` is empty, and then style adjacent classes based on that.

```
div.a:not(:empty) + .b {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yLxdnh37/)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for, is not possible with CSS only.

You can do this, though :

```css
.a:empty + .b {
   background: green;
}

.a + .b {
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b">Test2</div>

<div class="a">
    <div class="sub_a"></div>
</div>
<div class="b">Test2</div>
```

You could also do something like this :

```css
.a > .b {
   background: green;
}

.a > .sub_a ~ .b {
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">Test1</div>
</div>

<div class="a">
    <div class="sub_a"></div>
    <div class="b">Test2</div>
</div>
```